# $C=\{\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i$ | $\lambda_i\geq 0\text{ and }\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=1\}$ a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Why is $C=\{\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\mid\lambda_i\geq 0\text{ and }\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=1\}$ a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So this is like the convex hull of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which of course is bounded. However I don't see why it's necessarily closed?

I actually think I've read it somewhere, that this set should be compact, however I don't remember where. Does it have another name?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that the image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $w=\max_i \| v_i \|$. We have
$$
\forall \lambda_i, \,\left\| \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i\right\| \le mw.
$$
So $C$ is bounded.

Let $(\lambda_i^{(n)})_n$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers such that
$$
\forall n,\, \sum_{i=0}^m \lambda_i^{(n)}=1 \text{ and } \forall n, \forall i, \, \lambda_i^{(n)}\ge 0.
$$
and $\lambda_i^{(n)} \to \lambda_i$.
Taking the limits, we have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^m \lambda_i=1 \text{ and } \forall i, \, \lambda_i\ge 0,
$$
so $\sum_{i=0}^m \lambda_i v_i\in C$. This shows that $C$ is closed, so $C$ is closed and bounded, so $C$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^n$.